# EC2 connecting to RDS instance but still getting out of memory error

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an r3 EC2 instance with 122 GB RAM connected to a r3 RDS instance also with 122 GB RAM. I am connected via PHP CLI and most data transfers an queries happen properly.

Due to the massive nature of the database I've had to break the data into 700 tables. I have to run a query and extract 86,991 rows * 3,765 columns from different parts of these tables(all strings and integers) but I am running into out of memory errors at the 2 GB mark. I am storing everything in an array.

**Here is the error I am receiving:**

```
171/3765 complete xxx
172/3765 complete xxx
173/3765 complete xxx
174/3765 complete xxx
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1978662912) (tried to allocate 52 byt
es) in  on line 151
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() :0
PHP   2. mysqli_fetch_array() :151

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1978662912) (tried to allocate 52 bytes) i
n  on line 151

Call Stack:
    0.0004     137192   1. {main}() :0
  267.8024 1976770240   2. mysqli_fetch_array() :151
```

**Here is my code:**

```
//loop through each variables
$tqra3 = array();
$i = 1;
foreach($variableNames as &$vn){
    $vn2 = addslashes($vn);
    //look up location of variable
    $tq1 = "SELECT `location` FROM `$variableLocationTable` WHERE `Variable Name` = \"{$vn2}\";";
    $tqr1 = mysqli_query($db, $tq1);

    //table query error checking
    if($tqr1 === FALSE){
        $tqe1 = "error1: \r\n" . mysqli_error($db) ."\r\n";
        echo $tqe1;
        exit();
    }

    //fetch location of attribute
    $tqfa1 = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr1);
    $location = $tqfa1[0];

    //get needed attribute values
    $tq3 = "SELECT `id`, `$vn2` FROM $location WHERE `id` IN $concatIDs ORDER BY `id` ASC;";
    $tqr3 = mysqli_query($db, $tq3);

    //table query error checking
    if($tqr3 === FALSE){
        $tqe3 = "error3: \r\n" . mysqli_error($db) ."\r\n";
        echo $tqe3;
        exit();
    }

    //insert select statement results into array
    //ERROR LOCATION
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr3)){
        $id = $row3[0];
        $attributeMarker = $row3[1];
        $tqra3[$id][$vn] = $attributeMarker;
    }

    //error checking
    echo $i . "/" . $countVN . " complete " . $vn . " done" . "\r\n";
    $i++;
}
```

**Here are ways I have already tried to debug:**

1. I've tried `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)` (..I know it's bad but I'm just testing)
2. I've tried to set `memory_limit = 100000M`. When I do `ini_get('memory_limit')` it returns the value set in php.ini
3. I thought maybe my data structure was the problem so I tried a fixed array but it triggered the same error at 176/3765.
4. I've tried unbuffered queries but since I'm storing everything in memory before I write it out to a csv it doesn't seem to do much.
5. I've messed around with the DB parameter settings on the RDS instance in case there were some limits I was reaching on that end but it didn't help either. I specifically tried increasing the max packet size, cache size, and buffer pool size.
6. I gave PHP CLI real time privileges through task manager in case that could help but it didn't.
7. I've temporarily make a workaround where for every row, every column is looked up and then written to a csv to pretty much store nothing in memory, but it has exponentially increased the running time and is much too slow.

**Here are hints I need:**

I'm fairly certain the EC2 instance has the ability to store all of this in memory but it definitely shouldn't be running out of memory around the 2 GB mark. I'm thinking there is something I need in my config file or I need to adjust some privileges somewhere but I've currently hit a wall.

Comment: Are you running a 64bit PHP? Otherwise you'll never be able to allocate over 2**31

Comment: Besides the 32/64 bit question, PHP is probably not the best tool for this kind of job. Depending what you are trying to do with the data, you may want to look at an ETL tool like kettle.

Comment: Hi Marc thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that, I was just using the php given to me in my xampp install. I reinstalled the 64-bit version and the problem went away.